# Is it suitable to wire 'protected' li-ion cells in series and parallel? 2S6P

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, lithium

Here is the circuit designed to give about 7V. Each cell would be a protected cell.
Is it safe to connect these cells that way?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: It depends if you want to have fuse blow detection and thus resulting loss in Amp load rating for safety

Comment: The cells should be closely matched voltages (<100 mV)  before bridging them .

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Yes it is possible to closely match the voltages. I am just thinking safety wise. I don't care about a drop in max supply current or capacity (if it is that much)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look safe, no. If I read this correctly, it is 1P2S6P and it's neither cost efficient nor safe. First you connect the cells in parallel. Once you do that they become one self-balancing cell. Then put them in series. So basically 6P2S is what you need, P first, S second, and no more Ps after that. Otherwise single sells in series will drift without cell balancing and blow protection fuses, unless you add expensive cell-balancing controllers to each of 6 series.

Comment: Thanks! I suppose I can connect them in that configuration. Does it make any difference if they are 'protected' or not?

Comment: each of 6 cells in parallel (P) must be fused, which is what protection does I think. You still need a balancer/controller for 2S on top. Those can be cheap or expensive depending on how long you need the batteries to last